# facebook tracking who invited whom

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have an application that a user can invite his friends:

```
var request = {
    method: 'apprequests',
    message: 'message here',
    filters: ['app_non_users'],
    data: 'is this what i need to look at?'
};

FB.ui(request, function (response) {
        if (response && response.request_ids) {
   }
}
```

Now say two users A & B invite user C to join the app, and user C clicks on the invite box of user B. How can i monitor that? can i send the invitation with a php parameter so i can track such as "**http://app.facebook.com/myapp/?invitedFromUser=Id_Of_User_B**"

Or is the data option in Fb.ui is the key here? cause i can't seem to find any documentation on the specific option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to do this, as once the invitee clicks the request Facebook will append the "*request id*" to the URL.

So all you need to do is to read the request and check from whom it was sent. Below are a couple of links to read:

1. [Facebook documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/), to check the structure of the request
2. [How to send a request and save the response to DB](http://www.masteringapi.com/tutorials/how-to-send-an-application-request-using-the-facebook-graph-api/44/)
3. [How to handle the requests and advanced use of the `data` parameter](http://www.masteringapi.com/tutorials/how-to-handle-application-requests-using-the-facebook-graph-api/45/)